# Find all zero(s) in matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, find, zero

Please help me I want to find all zero elements in matrix in MATLAB.
For example, if matrix

```
A = [1 3 0; 2 4 9; 2 0 7]
```

the answer should be `(1,3)` and `(3,2)`.
But the real matrix I want to solve is very big. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/find.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I have seen the MATLAB tutorial but According to it, find: Find indices and values of "nonzero" element. That is why I posted this question.

Answer (score 3):

use `find`:

```
[r c] = find(A==0);
```

Comment: At last, I can do it. Thank you very much sir.